# Linked questions not working when there are more than one link in a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-questions

I don’t think the “Linked” panel is working when there are more then one link in a comment.  See my comment on this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54988/should-single-transferable-voting-stv-be-used-to-choose-the-best-example-questi).

(It may also be that the links are not updated when a comment is edited)

Comment: [Test link 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53207/search-with-votes-in-the-first-term-causes-the-sorting-tabs-to-change-search-pa) [Test link 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53201/last-voted-date-never-updates-after-you-change-your-vote)

Comment: I think comment editing has something to do with it. Similar problem here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62562/question-linking-broken

Answer (score 2):

Linked questions weren't being rebuilt when editing a comment; the fix will be pushed in the next build.