# Question Linking Broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Adding related links in a SO question comment to OP does not always seem to show all the possibly linked questions, only the first link provided.

For example, in my comment to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586923/counting-unicode-characters-in-c), I provided several links but only the first link was showing as "Linked" on the right hand side. The other links were added after an edit. Refresh issue?

Comment: A similar inquiry on the Linked section as from comments can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55830/linked-questions-not-working-when-there-are-more-than-one-link-in-a-comment). That issue may have been resolved, but I'm not really sure as the system has been rather inconsistent on this as of late.

Comment: @Grace: Seems it's an issue when the comment is edited

Comment: That is what my original answer on that question implied, but the behavior is no longer consistent as there may have been a fix of some sort applied recently.

Answer (score 2):

Linked questions weren't being rebuilt when editing a comment; the fix will be pushed in the next build.